# Шуфелька: діалектизм чи літературне слово?

Tags: іменники, діалектизми

Від старших людей чула таке висловлювання: “*Підмети хату. **Шуфелька** отам, є в кутку.*” Виникло питання, чи це діалектизм, чи може справді літературне слово? У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/shufeljka) такого слово не знайшла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53416/1068812.html) бачимо таку словникову статтю:

> **шуфелька** 
>   шуфе́лька → "шуфлі"

В ній є відсилання до наступної:

> **шуфлі** 
>   шу́флі (шу́фля) 1. лопата (ср, ст) 2. лопатка для сміття; совок (ср, ст)|| = смітярка
>   3. вул. рука (ср, ст).

В [Словнику лемківської говірки] знаходимо:

> **шуфелька**
>   - кы , ж. Ол.
>   Совочок, лопаточка.

На сайті [Ямельницька говірка та ямельницький словник](https://jamelnycia.io.ua/s204582/yamelnicka_govirka_ta_yamelnickiy_slovnik) також знаходимо це слово:

> **Шуфелька** – совочок, лопатка.

Отже, **шуфелька** - це діалектизм.

Answer (score 3):

*Шефелька* є пестливим словом, тому бажано шукати непестливого виду. Зміна подібна до *вафелька → вафля*, отже *шуфелька → шуфля*

Згаданий вами осідок, котрий має не тільки словника української мови в 11 книгах, а також вільного тлумачного словника, має [шуфля](http://sum.in.ua/f/shuflja):

> **шу́фля**, **-і**, *жіночий рід*, *західне*.
>   Лопата, *переважно* совкова, з широким квадратним ло́патнем.
>
> У порівнянні. *..Мілько Щурик — ..слава і пиха маленької вулиці, яка за сотні літ не породила жодної путньої людини, іно того нещасного Мілька, що навіть не мав ніг, а совгався на плиткому візочку, підпираючись загрубілими й чорними, як шуфлі, руками..* (Юрій Винничук, Мальва Ланда, 2004).

Як видно, має мітку *західне*, тому можна вважати *діялектизмом*, а не сучасною літературною мовою. Однак, через особливих письменників, як от Франко ([наступна цитата](//zbruc.eu/node/29755)), й існуванню колись ріжних вагомих варіяцій літературних норм, то загальна література має приклади вживу:

> *Дзвеніла залізна шуфля, накидаючи їх [вугільні брили] у огнище, але в котлі [локомотива] було ще тихо.*